# Fedora 19: Changing runlevel 3 to 5 and it fails to start in GUI

Tags: linux, virtualbox, fedora

I've installed Fedora 19 in VirtualBox. During the Installation I had choosed **Minimal Installation**. So its now working Runlevel 3 and not in GUI.

So I did

> ln -fs /lib/systemd/system/graphical.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target

And the default.target is changed to Graphical.target. After that I rebooted the Fedora and it is still booting through console mode and not in GUI. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Practically the only difference between `multi-user.target` and `graphical.target` is that the latter additionally starts `display-manager.service` if one exists.

*[They're not called "runlevel 3" & "runlevel 5" anymore.]*

But a minimal install doesn't have any display manager. You'll need to install one, such as GDM (the default for GNOME), and `systemctl enable` the corresponding service.

(For example, `systemctl enable gdm.service` will symlink it to "display-manager.service".)